# How to grants pg_read_server_files OR alternative on AWS RDS PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a python script to modify a PostgreSQL database with a csv file. The script, the csv and the database used to be on the same private server. I'd like to migrate on AWS so I do some experiments. My first attempt is to run the script on my server and modify the new PostgreSQL database created with RDS. So everything seems to work except that I don't have the pg_read_server_files role on my "main" database user. As far as I understand this is normal, but I don't know what I should do to achieve my mission.

Any ideas ?

Thanks for reading

Comment: As best I can tell, you will need to load that csv into memory in your python code and insert it via regular pg insert command.

Comment: The thing is csv files can be really huge, and my goal is to not modify previous scripts. Thanks for your comment

Comment: If it is a hosted database, how would you load the files onto the server so that you can use `COPY ... FROM '/file'`? You'll have to use `COPY ... FROM STDIN`.

Comment: Thank you Laurenz, indeed copy from stdin worked but I had to modify the script. It is not a big problem and I will adopt this solution. Nonetheless, does it mean that the use of pg_read_server_files is a practice to avoid in the future scripts ?

Comment: Yes, either don't use pg_read_server_files, or don't use RDS.